# ruby: how to convert hash into array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a hash that contains numbers as such:

```
{0=>0.07394653730860076, 1=>0.0739598476853163, 2=>0.07398647083461522}
```

it needs to be converted into an array like:

```
[[0, 0.07394653730860076], [1, 0.0739598476853163], [2, 0.07398647083461522]]
```

i tried my hash.values which gets me:

```
[0.07398921877505593, 0.07400253683443543, 0.07402917535044515]
```

I have tried multiple ways but i just started learning ruby.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this:

```
{0=>0.07394653730860076, 1=>0.0739598476853163, 2=>0.07398647083461522}.to_a
#=> [[0, 0.07394653730860076], [1, 0.0739598476853163], [2, 0.07398647083461522]]
```

Answer (score 7):

Definitely use the Hash#to_a method, which will produce exactly what you are looking for.

```
{0=>0.07394653730860076, 1=>0.0739598476853163, 2=>0.07398647083461522}.to_a
=> [[0, 0.07394653730860076], [1, 0.0739598476853163], [2, 0.07398647083461522]]
```

Hash#values will give you only the values of each element in the hash, while Hash#keys will give you just the keys. Fortunately, the default behavior of to_a is what you are looking for.